# RSpec issue: have_selector syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I am using Rspec 2.6.1 on Rails 3.1.

I am trying out a simple test from rails tutorial.  Here is what I have in a spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb :

```
  describe "GET 'home'" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get 'home'
      response.should be_success  #test1
      response.should have_selector ("title", :content => "Home") #test2
    end
  end
```

Everything works if I have only the first #test1 in the file. This means the setup is fine. But the moment I add #test2 I get bunch of errors and rspec is no longer able to run the tests.  The root error seems to be a syntax error and shows up as follows:

```
syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
```

I looked around and that seems to be the correct syntax.  Any Idea what the issue is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change

```
 response.should have_selector ("title", :content => "Home")
```

to

```
 response.should have_selector("title", :content => "Home")
```

I can't say (because I can't reproduce it right now) this will solve your problem but, for sure, it's not a good idea to have a space there.

Comment: Thanks Lucapette!  That was the issue.  I have not yet internalized this ruby idiosyncracy:).  I mean newline in code is fine but not space after function name! That somehow has not sunk in but I think I will be wiser after having lost a few hours on this today! Thanks again.